# Can't start Confluent Kafka Connect on Windows (NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig)

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

As title says, I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig` when starting ElasticSearch sink connector from command line.

I installed Confluent package by unzipping the `confluent-oss-5.0.0-2.11.zip` file in `C:\`.
Zookeeper, Kafka broker and ElasticSearch are up and running when I execute the following command (or any combination of relative paths):

```
> C:\confluent-5.0.0\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat C:\confluent-5.0.0\etc\kafka\connect-standalone.properties C:\confluent-5.0.0\etc\kafka-connect-elasticsearch\quickstart-elasticsearch.properties
```

This is my `connect-standalone.properties` file:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter     
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/confluent-5.0.0/share/java/
```

And my `quickstart-elasticsearch.properties` file:

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test2
key.ignore=true
connection.url=http://localhost:9200
type.name=kafka-connect
```

I looked for similar questions but they seemed to have problem with relative/absolute path for `plugin.path` property which I think is correctly set because if I change it, I get error about not finding ElasticSearchSink class.

I know that Windows is not fully supported for Confluent, but does anyone know the solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: `plugin.path` needs to be the full Windows path to the Java folder

Comment: When I update `plugin.path` to `plugin.path=C:\java\jdk1.8.0_51,C:\confluent-5.0.0\share\java` , I get the error: `Failed to find class that implements Connector`

Comment: Should just need `C:\confluent-5.0.0\share\java`, you wouldn't need actual Java installation (note: I've not tested this myself)

Comment: nope, still the same error.

Comment: I've escaped the backslashes and now I'm back to missing StorageSinkConnectorConfig class

Comment: Can you run `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\confluent-5.0.0\share\java;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;`, and then run `connect-standalone`?

Comment: Again the same error (missing StorageSinkConnectorConfig class)

Comment: Well, the only way I know how to get that class to be found is to manually set the java `CLASSPATH` variable to include the folder that contains that JAR, which should be the `kafka-connect-storage-common` folder. Otherwise, you can download Git Bash, or use WSL (on Windows 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Apparently, Kafka Connect tries to start all the plugins and fails when missing dependencies. So if you don't need default installed plugins (HDFS, S3...), you can delete those folders from `confluent-5.0.0/share/java/` folder.

I am still getting `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions, but they aren't related to ElasticSearch connector so I ignore them and when all those error messages finish printing, I can see that ES connector is up and I can see the data in my index.

Regarding the `plugin.path`, I set the full UNIX-like path to `/confluent-5.0.0/share/java/` with root (`/`) being the `C:` and start the `connect-standalone.bat` from `/confluent-5.0.0/bin/windows` folder.